# Detect local devices using HTML5 websocket

Tags: javascript, ios, html, websocket

I'm working on a project which uses HTML5 WebSockets to connect with an iOS App. I need to display a list of near by (within the same local WiFi network) iPhones/iPads inside the webpage.

1. Is it possible to use any discovery mechanism like Bonjour to achieve this?
2. Is there any way to detect the local IP address from the website (using Javascript or from server side script) so that I can scan the local IP range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking to match devices on the same network, you could just check the public IP, since everyone connected to the same router will likely share one. That said, while a native iOS app should be able to detect a local IP address, I don't know of any way to do so using Javascript.

The one exception is if you have a server running inside the local network (or a custom binary running on their machine). It doesn't sound from your description like this is an option for you, but in case it is, a server within the user's LAN will see their local IP *rather* than their public IP. It could then relay that to a public server if needed.

I'd love to be proven wrong though, because I could think of some really cool things to do if it were possible.

Comment: This answer is now out of date. https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-local-ip-address

Comment: Very cool! It's also probably worth mentioning that there's a commented version of that code in the page source of http://net.ipcalf.com/

Comment: After thinking about this for a moment: Keep in mind that many networks use the same IP addresses internally, like 192.168.1.x or 172.16.0.x. A local IP address alone isn't enough to determine what other devices are on your same network, because you could have 3 users that have the internal IP of 192.168.1.117. You should be able to work around this by using a combination of someone's public *and* private IP.

Comment: Also, many networks (especially corporate or home "guest" networks) disallow direct device-to-device communication. This means that you'll probably run into trouble if you try communicating directly with another user that's on the same network. It may work on some networks, but fail on others.